# Why do IBAN transfers sometimes take multiple days?

Tags: money-transfer

Sometimes IBAN transfers can arrive the day they are made, and at most (at least in Germany) I think they can take 5 days to arrive in the recipients bank account.

Why? What is going on that makes them take time?

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about domestic or international transfers? At least in the Netherlands, domestic transfers are guaranteed to be completed next business day if issued after 15:30, same business day if issued earlier. (The new "Instant Payment" system changed that though, such transfers are done in seconds.) International transfers can take longer.

Comment: Domestic. A payment was sent some time Thursday afternoon. It hadn’t arrived by 14:50 Monday. It may take up to or more than 48 hours (of working days) to arrive. Just curious why. Thank you